# Error when running R code for anova in python

Tags: python, r, anova, rpy2

I am trying to use ANOVA in python but using the R code with the help of the rpy2 package. In below, `code stats.lm()` works but not `stats.aov()`

```py
import pandas as pd
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

stats = importr('stats')
R = ro.r

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'subject':['1','2','3','4','5','1','2','3','4','5'],
    'group':['1','1','1','2','2','1','1','1','2','2'],
    'session':['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2'],
    'covar':['1', '2', '0', '2', '1', '1', '2', '0', '2', '1'],
    'result':[-6.77,6.11,5.67,-7.679,-0.0930,0.948,2.99,6.93,6.30,9.98]
})

rdf = ro.conversion.py2rpy(df)
result = stats.lm('covar ~ group*session', data=rdf)
print(R.summary(result).rx2('coefficients'))

result2 = stats.aov('covar ~ group*session', data=rdf)
```

I am getting this error.

> "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is due to passing a string formula into `stats.aov` and not formula object. Consider using stats package's `as.formula` (translated to `as_formula` in rpy2) to cast string formula or `reformulate` to build string with string parameters:

```py
results = stats.aov(stats.as_formula("covar ~ group*session"), data=df)
print(R.summary(results))

results = stats.aov(stats.reformulate("group*session", "covar"), data=df)
print(R.summary(results))

#               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#
# group          1    0.6  0.6000    0.72  0.429
# 
# session        1    0.0  0.0000    0.00  1.000
# 
# group:session  1    0.0  0.0000    0.00  1.000
# 
# Residuals      6    5.0  0.8333
```

Comment: thank you so much, that answered my doubt

Comment: is there a way i can read and understand more about rpy2 other than the rpy2 documentation?

Comment: Nothing I know of since `rpy2` is a Python package. But actually, your issue is an R error. Since you have R installed, always test code there for debugging.